# How do I unsubscribe a handler in Bacon.js?

Tags: bacon.js

I'm learning to use the fantastic [Bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) library for functional reactive programming. Adding handlers to a property or stream is easy:

```
handler = function(value){... do something ...}
property.onValue(handler)
```

Say somewhere down the line I want to cancel this subscription, like this (pseudocode):

```
property.unsubscribe(handler)
```

Is there a way to do this with Bacon.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ["cleaning up"](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) section of the docs:

> Call the dispose() function that was returned by the subscribe() call.

So you have to save the return of `onValue`:

```
var dispose = property.onValue(handler)
```

Then invoke it to remove the listener:

```
dispose();
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/9V8Zd/3/)

Comment: Thank you McGarnagle! I know it had to be somewhere, but for the life of me I couldn't see it. :)

Answer (score 11):

Both answers above are correct. Personally, I've never used either solution though. In fact, they mainly exist for internal purposes and for writing custom combinators and integrations.

So instead I recommend combinators like `take`, `takeWhile` and `takeUntil`. In an FRP application, the signal that triggers the need can usually be modeled as an EventStream. In that case you can do

```
var data, stopper // EventStreams
data.takeUntil(stopper).onValue( .. )
```

Comment: It'd be great to see an example of this. Is `stopper` just a `Bus` that you use for control flow?

Comment: Well for example, if you want to react to mouse moves and stop that when a key is pressed, you'll do `mouseMoves.takeUntil(keyPress).onValue(..)`. Or if you want to react only once, you'll do `clicks.take(1).onValue(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email):

stream.subscribe(f) subscribes given handler function to event stream. Function will receive Event objects (see below). The subscribe() call returns a unsubscribe function that you can call to unsubscribe. You can also unsubscribe by returning Bacon.noMore from the handler function as a reply to an Event.